# How to read SNI extension in Controller Action method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a requirement to have two certificates from different certificate providers for the same domain. I was able to achieve this using SNI. The clients will get corresponding certificates based on the SNI extension sent in the Client Hello. Please refer to the image below for the SNI extension sent in Client Hello(I captured this using Wireshark).

[image]

Now the client is able to successfully establish TLS connection.

I would like to log the SNI header received from the client in the Controller action method for debugging purposes. But I'm not sure how to get SNI header in the action method.

I'm using .NET Core Web API targeted to Framework 4.8 and c#.

Comment: Have you examined the `this.Request.Headers` object where `this` is the controller?

Comment: Yes, I checked this.Request.Headers. But I'm not able to find the SNI extension.